# using -force_key_frames in ffmpeg with libx265

Tags: ffmpeg, transcoding

I'm trying encode a video stream using HEVC with ffmpeg and create a MPEG-TS file. I need to be able to insert IDR frames to certain locations in the stream. I came across the flag `-force_key_frames` under ffmpeg documentation, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is the command I tried:

`ffmpeg -s:v 1280x720 -i input.yuv -c:v libx265 -x265-params crf=20:keyint=25:fps=25:preset=ultrafast -force_key_frames 1,12,30,111 -f mpegts out.ts`

Please help me to sort out this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ffmpeg's `libx265` wrapper is very minimal, and doesn't pass on very many settings.  e.g. `-pass 1` requires manually setting `-x265-params pass=1`.

Also, if x265 is anything like x264, don't use ultrafast except for lossless or for testing things.

sorry for not taking the time to dig this up myself, but have a look and see if you can get your desired I frame locations into x265-params.  Probably not, though.

If you want to hack some C code, have a look at `libx264.c` and `libx265.c`, and maybe you can see how to ffmpeg sends frame-type requests to x264.  And maybe you can port that to the libx265 wrapper.